# How I can delete the vertical bar in vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vi, vim-plugin

[image]

I am trying to delete the vertical bar but I don't know what is the code in .vimrc I should disable to remove it.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do not put answers here in the comment section. Make an answer and put it there.

Comment: That feature is disabled by default. If you managed to enable it, you can certainly manage to disable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .vimrc:

`set colorcolumn=""`